Unable to phrase error while using query and select with condition
QUERY(A7 IMPORTRANGE( sheet id.."DOD tracker!A2:H"), "SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7 WHERE col2 = DATE '" & TEXT(B2, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "' ", 0)
Where each column will have number and text except B as it is date
...you can add an example sheet with  columns as Name Date task worked hrs sheet link count and target respectively....
I am getting error --Unable to phrase query string function parameter 2 NO_COLUMN:COL1....and if you can solve this I want to add another row after the last row of the result with sum of the utilizes hrs column count and target...

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
